# Splash screen to Home screen navigation - Flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a Flutter app and have decided to introduce a splash screen in the same. To navigate to the home screen from the splash screen, normally we use Navigator. But there is one issue that I find in the Navigator method. Whenever i'm popping or pushing a screen, there is a visible navigation, i.e. I can see the screen moving left, right, up or down. What I want to achieve, is that the splash screen should disappear instead of sliding away from the screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey Pratik, Can you please share code what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add native splash screen, if you don't want that visible navigation. To add splash screen in your app properly. Please follow the guide: [Creating native splash screen](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)

If you are feeling lazy, you can just use the following package : [Splash Screen Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash). This package is easy to use just read the documentation before installing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [flutter_native_splash: ^2.0.5](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

```
This package will provide you native splash screen for your apps.
```

But if you want to **disappear your current screen and go to next screen** you can use this class *custom_route.dart*. This class provide you an animation like disappear.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class FadePageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
      FadePageRoute({
        required WidgetBuilder builder,
        RouteSettings? settings,
      }) : super(
              builder: builder,
              settings: settings,
            );
    
      @override
      Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 600);
    
      @override
      Widget buildTransitions(
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
      ) {
        if (settings.name == "/auth") {
          return child;
        }
    
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: child,
        );
      }
    }
```

> and finally

```
 onPressed: () {                
               Navigator.of(context).push(FadePageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => YourScreen(),
                        ));
                    },
```